# Extract API calls from an APK

Tags: android, api, static-analysis, malware-detection

How could i extract API calls/System calls sequence from APK? I have decompiled source code from APK now i want to know if there is a tool that can extract all system calls made by that app from source code.

Answer (score -1):

You should use CuckooDroid for analyze APK files. I installed it and I use. So I can get all services, activities etc. You can look there [enter link description here](https://github.com/idanr1986/cuckoo-droid)
or [enter link description here](http://www.cuckoosandbox.org/)

They provide to get all functions about APK.