# How can I extract API calls from an APK file?

Tags: android, python, api, apk, static-analysis

Using Python, I am trying to extract the API calls that an Android application makes, given it's .apk file.

Is there a way to parse/extract names of the APIs used by a package through static analysis of its APK?

### Here's what I've tried/discovered so far....

I have seen this question [posted before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982143/extract-api-calls-from-an-apk) but haven't been able to follow the (very limited) answers to a working solution.

I know there are some tools such as [Cartographer](https://github.com/gorla/appmining) that accomplish this among other things, but I haven't been able to get the relevant portions of the code working. Another tool [CHABADA](https://software.imdea.org/~alessandra.gorla/papers/Gorla-CHABADA-ICSE14.pdf) can do it but is not open-source.

I have been able to get some other information from APKs, such as the external classes using [Androguard](http://androguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), the components of the `AndroidManifest.xml` file using [APK Static Analyzer](https://github.com/s3bap3/apk-analyser), and using [Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/), I can decode the manifest into a readable format and also get the smali files.

[Another previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972250/extracting-all-api-calls-from-smali-files-in-android-apk) asks about parsing the smali files for APIs, from lines like the follwing:

```
  invoke-virtual {p0, v0}, Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager;->getNetworkInfo(I)Landroid/net/NetworkInfo;
```

but this doesn't appear to be a useful method since `invoke-virtual` or `invoke-direct` do not always indicate API usage, and parsing the smali files is a heavier task than if there were some way to just extract the called APIs by statically-analyzing the APK itself.

[Dexlib2](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/tree/master/dexlib2/src/main/java/org/jf/dexlib2) has also been recommended but I don't see where it can extract API calls, and it's all in Java whereas I've been working in Python.

The tool [API Key detector](https://github.com/alessandrodd/api_key_detector) is giving me the API Keys used, but I don't know how to get the API names from this.

Any solutions?

### Update #1

I've used Androguard to generate CFG's in the .gexf format as per @ShirishSingh, which can give me nodes in the form:

```
<node id="0" label="Landroid/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatHoneycomb; newOnQueryTextListener (Landroid/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatHoneycomb$OnQueryTextListenerCompatBridge;)Ljava/lang/Object;">
<attvalues>
<attvalue id="1" value="Landroid/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatHoneycomb;"/>
<attvalue id="2" value="newOnQueryTextListener"/>
<attvalue id="3" value="(Landroid/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatHoneycomb$OnQueryTextListenerCompatBridge;)Ljava/lang/Object;"/>
<attvalue id="6" value="false"/>
</attvalues>
</node>
```

I can see above that `newOnQueryTextListener` is a method used from `Landroid`. However there are many other nodes of methods from internal classes. How can I differentiate the nodes of methods from internal classes, to those imported from other libraries, to those that are actual API calls?

Comment: Do you need control flow graphs? There are some ways to get the API calls from APKs. Do you need the entire API call or just the package name/class name/method name?

Comment: @ShirishSingh I don't need the control flow graphs for now, just having the package/class/method names of called APIs would be very helpful.

Comment: I can recommend some tools which generate CFGs from APK, then you can write a script to extract the API calls from them. Will that work for you?

Comment: @ShirishSingh That would be helpful yes, thanks. Ideally I was hoping for some sort of lightweight tool that can return the API names after static-analysis of the APK, but if generating the CFG first is the best solution, then yes I would appreciate your recommendations!

Comment: You can refer to Androguard here: https://github.com/jrgifford/androguard. Use the androgexf.py script to generate CFG. Command: androgexf.py -i <Path to APK file> -o <Output File>

Comment: Let me know if you face any hurdle.

Comment: @ShirishSingh I've added an update to my post regarding the .gexf CFGs. Please let me know if you have any more info

Comment: refer to the page: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/package-summary. You can extract all the Android-based classes from here and check against the classes from the nodes in gexf file. This will give you a list of internal API calls.
For extracting the API calls within the application, you can extract the package name of the APK and then refer to the classes within those packages.
The rest of the API calls are from the libraries.

Answer (score 2):

dx.get_classes() will return all the classes. You can then check the ones marked as "EXTERNAL"  for API calls. See the link:
[Using the analysis object](https://androguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/gettingstarted.html#using-the-analysis-object)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to comment on the top, but for the reason that I'm new in stack I can't. Is it not better just call dx.get_methods() of Androguard? then check from there? without creating the file CFG?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apk-analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer) for the apk dissection.

I used the following command before `apkanalyzer dex packages [apk-file]`. The output of this command has all the details of the defined/referenced packages/classes/methods/fields. The details of how to parse the output is given in the link.